# add a sibling to a node of xml in R

Tags: r, xml2

how to add siblings to a1 and a2 node in R?

input : `<a><a1>123</a1> <a2>222</a2>  </a>`

target `<a><a1>123</a1> <a2>222</a2> <a3>222</a3> </a>`

```
library(xml2)
x <- read_xml("<a><a1>123</a1> <a2>222</a2>  </a>"); 
xml_add_sibling(xml_child(x), "<a3>string</a3>"); 
x
```

Currently, it outpus: `<a><a1>123</a1> <<a3>string</a3>/> <a2>222</a2>  </a>`.

why there are another `<` and `/>`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the function parameters correctly. The second argument in `xml_add_sibling` is `.value`, and should be the tag name. Instead of giving the tag the tagname `a3`, you are giving it the tagname `<a3>string</a3>`, which is why your extra angle brackets have appeared.

Simply pass the tagname `a3` to the `.value` argument and enter the contents of the tag in a subsequent unnamed argument as advised in the docs:

> `.value`       node to insert.

> `...`            If named attributes or namespaces to set on the node, if unnamed text to assign to the node.

```r
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("<a><a1>123</a1> <a2>222</a2>  </a>")
xml_add_sibling(xml_child(x), .value = "a3", 'string')
x
#> {xml_document}
#> <a>
#> [1] <a1>123</a1>
#> [2] <a3>string</a3>
#> [3] <a2>222</a2>
```